# How do I use a function as a variable in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, variables, events

I want to be able to put the code in one place and call it from several different events.

Currently I have a selector and an event:

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").on('click', function () {
  // code works here //
});
```

I use the same code elsewhere in the file, however using a different selector.

```
$(".product_table").on('change', '.edit_quantity', function () {
  // code works here //
});
```

I have tried following the advice given elsewhere on StackOverflow, to simply give my function a name and then call the named function but that is not working for me. The code simply does not run.

```
$(".product_table").on('change', '.edit_quantity', function () {
  calculateTotals() {
    // code does not work //
  }
});
```

So, I tried putting the code into it's own function separate from the event and call it inside the event, and that is not working for me as well.

```
calculateTotals() {
  // code does not work //
}
```

So what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: why not just `calculateTotals()`

Comment: why are you defining a function inside of an event handler? That too wrong syntax.

Comment: Define the function outside the event handler: `function calculateTotals() {}`. Then you can call `calculateTotals()` inside your event handler.

Comment: @ÖzgürErsil Thanks for the feedback - Sorry I am new to JS.  I am not sure I understand your comment. I tried putting the code inside it's own function adn then firing it after an on click event,, but it does not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could pass your function as a variable.

You want to add listeners for events after the DOM has loaded, [JQuery](https://jquery.com/) helps with `$(document).ready(fn);` ([ref](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)).

To fix your code:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $("input[type='checkbox']").on('click', calculateTotalsEvent)
   $(".product_table").on('change', '.edit_quantity', calculateTotalsEvent)
 });

 function calculateTotalsEvent(evt) {
   //do something 
   alert('fired');
 }
```

---

**Update:**
Vince asked:

> This worked for me - thank you, however one question: you say, "pass your function as a variable" ... I don't see where you are doing this. Can you explain ? tks. – [Vince](https://stackoverflow.com/users/987051/vince)

---

**Response:**
In JavaScript you can assign functions to variables.
You probably do this all the time when doing:

```
function hello() {
  //
}
```

You define `window.hello`.
You are adding to Global Namespace.
[JavaScript window object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_window.asp)
This generally leads to ambiguous JavaScript architecture/spaghetti code.
I organise with a Namespace Structure.
A small example of this would be:

**app.js**

```
var app = {
  controllers: {}
};
```

You are defining `window.app` (just a [json](http://www.json.org/) object) with a key of `controllers` with a value of an object.

**something-ctlr.js**

```
app.controllers.somethingCtlr.eventName = function(evt) {
  //evt.preventDefault?
  //check origin of evt? switch? throw if no evt? test using instanceof?
  alert('hi');
}
```

You are defining a new key on the previously defined `app.controllers.somethingCtlr`called `eventName`.

You can invoke the function with `();`.

app.controllers.somethingCtlr.eventName();

This will go to the key in the object, and then invoke it. 
You can pass the function as a variable like so.

```
anotherFunction(app.controllers.somethingCtlr.eventName);
```

You can then invoke it in the function like so

```
function anotherFunction(someFn) { someFn();}
```

The `javascript` files would be structured like so:

```
  +-html
  +-stylesheets
  +-javascript-+
               +-app-+
                     +-app.js
                     +-controllers-+
                                   +-something-ctlr.js
```

Invoke via [chrome developer tools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools) with:

app.controllers.somethingCtlr.eventName();

You can pass it as a variable like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button').click(app.controllers.somethingCtlr.eventName);
});
```

JQuery ([ref](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)).

I hope this helps,
Rhys

Comment: This worked for me - thank you, however one question: you say, "pass your function as a variable" ... I don't see where you are doing this. Can you explain ? tks.

Comment: To elaborate, in one of my events I had to use this sytax to make it work:

"  $("input[type='checkbox']").on('click',calculateTotals(),function() {
        $(this).closest("tr.delete_row").remove();
"

Comment: Functions in Javascript are what we call "first class objects".  This means that a function is an object that can be passed around and assigned to a variable.  In the example you provide, you're creating a function and immediately passing it into a call, the same way you do with 'click'.  You could also call ``var c = 'click'; $('input').on(c, ...etc``

Comment: Anywhere you can assign a value to a variable, you can also assign it a function, and anywhere you can use a variable, you can use one that has a function assigned to it.  ``var x = function() {};`` is no different than saying ``var x = 5;``

Comment: I have updated my answer in response to your comment @Vince

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you were on the right track but had some incorrect syntax.  No need for `{ }` when calling a function.  This code should behave properly once you add code inside of the `calculateTotals` function.

```
$(".product_table").on('change', '.edit_quantity', function () {
  calculateTotals();
});

$("input[type='checkbox']").on('click',function() {
  calculateTotals();
});

function calculateTotals() {
  //your code...
}
```

Comment: for some reason I had already tried your approach and could not make it work - however thanks for the feedback !

Answer (score 0):

You could just condense it all into a single function. The onchange event works for both the check box and the text input (no need for a click handler). And jQuery allows you to add multiple selectors.

```js
$('input[type=checkbox], .product_table .edit_quantity').on('change', function() {

  console.log('do some calculation...');

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product_table">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <input class="edit_quantity">
</div>
```